# Ionic2 x Angular: Service resetting on nav change

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic2

Using Angular2 in Ionic2

Utilizing a userService to login and pull a user from the server, however on a nav change (or click of existing page in nav) it does a reload that is causing the service to reinitialize (I think) and emptying the user in the service.

How do I retain the user / user$ variable in the service as I navigate throughout the app?

Comment: I assume you're providing the service in a `@Component()`, but you should provide it in `@NgModule()` instead to have a single instance for your application. If the `@NgModule()` is of a lazy loaded module you need to provide it using `forRoot`. See also https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#forroot

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its the right way to handle it, but for now I'm utilizing storage and having the userService check storage when reinitiated.